# How to show all Info window in iOS Google maps without tapping on Marker?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to create markers without tapping. But i cant display all infoWindows. It only show one infowindow on last marker.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *markersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
        marker.appearAnimation=YES;
        marker.opacity = 0.0;
        mapView.selectedMarker = marker;
        marker.map = mapView;
        [markersArray addObject:marker];
    }
}
```

and custom Infowindow:

```
- (UIView*)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    CustomInforwindow *customView =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomInforwindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    return customView;
}
```

Comment: place two markers at same place(Do maintain some gap in between both) and remove interaction for both. for example marker1.position=Locationcoorsinate2dobject; marker2.position=Locationcoorsinate2dobject;| marker1.tappable=false; marker2.tappable=false; Now the magic is gonna happens marker2.groundanchor=CGPointMake(marker1.groundanchor.x,marker1.gorundanchor.y+2‌​.7); Hope this helps Happy coding :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can display one InfoWindow at a time.

```
mapView.selectedMarker = marker; this will open the infowindow for the last marker
```

If you want to show multiple markers then you should make marker that contains both the marker and the info window .

Hope this helps.

Comment: if i want to open more than one window then is it possible ? My requirement is to open more than one window

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Any alternate solution for that ?

Comment: you can make the marker image as of the selectedmarker image

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to implement your suggestion.

Comment: place two markers at same place(Do maintain some gap in between both) and remove interaction for both.

for example marker1.position=Locationcoorsinate2dobject;
                    marker2.position=Locationcoorsinate2dobject;|
                    marker1.tappable=false;
                    marker2.tappable=false;
                    Now the magic is gonna happens
                    marker2.groundanchor=CGPointMake(marker1.groundanchor.x,marker1.gorundanchor.y+2.7);

Hope this helps
Happy coding :)