# open annotation automatically from array list

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mkmapview, mapbox

I am trying to open all my annotation pins automatically so that the user does not need to actually touch them. I am generating the annotation pins automatically using this method

```
filteredLocations.map {
        (location) in
        let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = location.Neighborhood
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:     location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        mapView.setCenter((mapView.userLocation?.coordinate)!,zoomLevel:11, animated:true)
        mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
```

I tried using the method mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true) , but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score -1):

You can display one InfoWindow for the google marker in iOS at a time.

```
mapView.selectedMarker = marker;
```

this will open the infoWindow for the last selected marker.
If you want to show multiple markers at once then you should make custom marker that contains both the marker and the info window.

Hope this is helpful for you.
Refer: [How to show all Info window in iOS Google maps without tapping on Marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820740/how-to-show-all-info-window-in-ios-google-maps-without-tapping-on-marker)

Comment: This answer may be correct for Google, but the question is about Mapbox.